# AngularJS $sceDelegate RegExp : Trouble whitelisting similar domains?

Tags: javascript, regex, angularjs, iframe

I need to whitelist some url's passed as `{{vars}}` to some iframes `src`'s.

Domain names are :

```
1 : http://chateauversailles.fr
2 : http://www.chateauversailles-spectacles.fr/
```

This works for all #1 urls :

```
$sceDelegateProvider.resourceUrlWhitelist(['self', new RegExp('^(http[s]?):\/\/(w{3}.)?chateauversailles\.fr/.+$')]);
```

As soon as I try the sames rule on domain #2 :

```
$sceDelegateProvider.resourceUrlWhitelist(['self', new RegExp('^(http[s]?):\/\/(w{3}.)?chateauversailles\.fr/.+$')]);
$sceDelegateProvider.resourceUrlWhitelist(['self', new RegExp('^(http[s]?):\/\/(w{3}.)?chateauversailles\-spectacles\.fr/.+$')]);
```

It breaks all iframes src's, including domain #1 calls with the usual $sce error: `[$sce:insecurl] Blocked loading resource from url not allowed by $sceDelegate policy`.

If I try putting statement #2 before #1, Domain #1 urls are whitelisted, but not #2.

I suspect the culprit is the Regexp, but they seem pretty fine to me, but obviously not enough for $sce.

Comment: Try `$sceDelegateProvider.resourceUrlWhitelist(['self', new RegExp('^(https?):\\/\\/(w{3}\\.)?chateauversailles(-spectacles)?\\.fr/.+$')]);` as a single statement.

Comment: @stribizhev — That's the one. Thank you. Please turn your comment into an answer so I can upvote you.

Comment: Posted. Glad it turned out working for you.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can "merge" both statements into one using an optional group:

```
$sceDelegateProvider.resourceUrlWhitelist(['self', new RegExp('^(https?):\\/\\/(w{3}\\.)?chateauversailles(-spectacles)?\\.fr/.+$')]);
```

Note that you need to use double escaping when using a RegExp constructor.

**REGEX EXPLANATION**:

- `^` - Start of string anchor
- `(https?)` - A capturing group matching `http` or `https` (note you can remove the round brackets if you are not using backreferences)
- `:\\/\\/` - matches `://` literally (note you do not have to escape the slash in the constructor as it does not allow delimiters, so you can write `://`)
- `(w{3}\\.)?` - An optional capturing group (because of `?` quantifier) that matches the letter `w` , exactly 3 occurrences and a literal dot
- `chateauversailles` - matches the specified letter sequence 1 time
- `(-spectacles)?` - The optional group that matches `-spectacles` or nothing due to `?` quantifier.
- `\\.fr/` - matches `.fr/` literally
- `.+` - matches any 1 or more characters other than a newline
- `$` - end of string.

Comment: What a great, detailed answer. A fine regex tutorial as well.